# jQuery modal doesn't close when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

I am using this jQuery modal [here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/Super-Simple-Modal-Popups-with-jQuery-CSS3-Transitions.html) but he onclick event for the outside div is not firing.

This means that the modal is not closing if pressed outside of it.

I have tried making a timeout and separate the overlay on click event but with no luck.

```
  $(".js-modal-close").on("click", function() {
        $("#WidgetContainer").toggle("slow");
        $(".modal-box, .modal-overlay").fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(".modal-overlay").remove();
        });
    });
setTimeout(() => {

    $(".modal-overlay").on("click", function() {
        $("#WidgetContainer").toggle("slow");
        $(".modal-box, .modal-overlay").fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(".modal-overlay").remove();
        });
    });
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of your timeout. The reason why it's not working is because the element with the class `modal-overlay` isn't in the DOM yet.

You can use event delegation.
`$(document).on("click", ".modal-overlay", function() { ... });`